# How to get out integer from database using IDataReader and Mapper

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf, stored-procedures, ado.net

I'm very new in programming and this is my first post (question) here, so please don't judge me.

I'm trying to build my first individual WCF service for my project. Let me first display my code , so it will be easier to understand.

This is my data access layer:

```
public class DataAccessLayer : IDisposable
{
    string DBConnectionString = "DBCS";

    public int ValidateUser(string employeeLogin, string employeePassword)
    {
        int outputResult = 0;
        try
        {
            DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();

            Database db = factory.Create(DBConnectionString);
            string storedProcedureName = "uspValidateUser";

            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcedureName);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@EmployeeLogin", DbType.String, employeeLogin);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@EmployeePassword", DbType.String, employeePassword);
            db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "@OutRes", DbType.Int32, outputResult);

            using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
            {
                Mapper.Reset(); 
                Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Int32>();
                outputResult = (int)Mapper.Map<IDataReader, Int32>(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return outputResult;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspValidateUser] 
    @EmployeeLogin VARCHAR(20),
    @EmployeePassword VARCHAR(20),
    @OutRes int Output
AS
    SET @OutRes = (select count(*) 
                   from dbo.tblEmployee 
                   where EmployeeLogin = @EmployeeLogin 
                     and EmployeePassword = @EmployeePassword)

    if (@OutRes = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        set @OutRes = 1 --Login is correct
    end
    else
    BEGIN
        set @OutRes = 0 -- Login is incorrect
    END
```

And code behind my web form:

```
public int ValidateUser(string employeeLogin, string employeePassword)
{
    int outputResults = 0;

    try
    {
        using (HospitalWCFService.ContractsClient objWCFService = new HospitalWCFService.ContractsClient())
        {
            outputResults = objWCFService.ValidateUser(employeeLogin, employeePassword);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lgnEmployeeLogin.FailureText = ex.Message;
    }

    return outputResults;
}

protected void ValidateUser(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    int outputResults = 0;

    outputResults = ValidateUser(lgnEmployeeLogin.UserName, lgnEmployeeLogin.Password);

    if (outputResults == 1)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = lgnEmployeeLogin.UserName.ToString(); 
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(lgnEmployeeLogin.UserName, lgnEmployeeLogin.RememberMeSet);
    }
    else
    {
        lgnEmployeeLogin.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
    }
}
```

To get user credentials I'm using login control `lgnEmployeeLogin`.

I'm having problems of retrieving that output integer `@OutRes` parameter from database using `Mapper` (I need to use `mapper`)

If it is possible, please explain solution in easiest language possible as I might not understand difficult technical slang.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lack of answers could be because you say that you have to use `mapper` - but I chose to ignore that, because `ExecuteReader` is for dealing with the rows and columns returned by a stored procedure, not for its output parameters.  The stored procedure you provided has **no** result set!

This could be as simple as

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery();
OutputResult = db.Parameters( "@OutRes").value
```

to be clear, this replaces your  `using...ExecuteReader` block

Also note: your code did not deal with opening (and closing) the SQL connection (`db.Connection.Open();`, so I ignored that here too.